# C# 2015 - Gridview selected rows to RDLC report - Per page one row

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, rdlc

I am working on `C# 2015` windows application.

The basic idea is to get the records from the database and display in to the gridview. And print the selected records of grid view using `RDLC` report.

See the screenshot below for the basic idea.

[image]

Now, my `print button` code is as below:

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<customer> lstCustomer = new List<customer>();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgCustomers.SelectedRows)
    {
        customer c = new customer();
        c.id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[dgCustomers.Columns["id"].Index].Value);
        c.firstName = row.Cells[dgCustomers.Columns["first_name"].Index].Value.ToString();
        c.firstName = row.Cells[dgCustomers.Columns["last_name"].Index].Value.ToString();
        lstCustomer.Add(c);
    }

    frmReport r = new frmReport();
    r.Show();

    ReportViewer v = r.Controls.Find("reportViewer1", true).FirstOrDefault() as ReportViewer;
    v.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "bolt.rptBolt.rdlc";

    ReportDataSource dataset = new ReportDataSource("ReportDataSet1", lstCustomer);

    v.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    v.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataset);
    v.LocalReport.Refresh();
    v.RefreshReport();
    this.Hide();
}
```

See, I have created a `List lstCustomer` of class `customer` and added objects of the selected rows' cell values into it.

I have created a new form `frmReport` to display the report and added a `reportviewer` into it.

I have also taken an `Rdlc` report named `rptBolt.rdlc` and added it to the report viewer.

I have set the `datasource` of report with my list.

But now, I am not sure how to bind id, first name and last name into the report's text boxes.

**P.S. I want separate page for each record.**

I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone knows?

Comment: Also let me know if am I doing anything wrong or how to handle this different way?

Comment: No .NET experts available now-a-days in stack overflow??

Comment: Tell me any alternate way if am I following something wrong. Any experts please?

Comment: Please help me.. The bounty is going to be expired in 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,
In the frmReport, create one property called as `ReportId` and use as below.

```
/* Below Code goes to frmReport.cs */
//after the frmReport()
public int ReportId;

//In your forms where u have rdlc
frmReport r = new frmReport();
r.ReportId = GetTheSelectedRecordFromGridView();
r.Show();

ReportViewer v = r.Controls.Find("reportViewer1", true).FirstOrDefault() as ReportViewer;
v.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "bolt.rptBolt.rdlc";
//Apply your ReportId to filter the record
//But it is good, to apply this filter to the original database call/query
lstCustomer = lstCustomer.Where(x=>x.Id==ReportId).ToList();
ReportDataSource dataset = new ReportDataSource("ReportDataSet1", lstCustomer);
v.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
v.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataset);
v.LocalReport.Refresh();
v.RefreshReport();
this.Hide();

private int GetTheSelectedRecordFromGridView()
{
 //Write your logic, to get the selected Id;
}
```

Pass the reportId to frmReport, filter the record from database, build Report dataset with the desired fields, bind with reportviewer and display id, firstname and lastname fields.

Hope you got the logic / idea.

Comment: I want to display the id into the text box of the report. What if I take a text boxes in ```rptBolt.rdlc``` and set the ```id```, ```first name``` and ```last name``` fields into it. Per record there will be a new page that it will be easy to me to print them. How to achieve this?

Comment: Yes I can understand but what properties I need to set in to the report textbox to display id, first name and last name into it as well as what kind of settings I need to do to display one record per page?

Comment: ReportViewer can fetch the data from your report dataset.